# Swift: Login with a google using the Authfication of Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to Login with a google acount using the Authfinication of Firebase.
But, I failed to Login.

I implemented along the following docs.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui?hl=en

The following error message was output by authUI when logging with google account.
If you know a solution, please let me know.

**Log**

> user:  nil
>
> error:  Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17004 "OAuth2 client id in access token audience is not found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=OAuth2 client id in access token audience is not found., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL})

**code**

```
public func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?){
    print("user: ", user as Any)
    print("error: ", error as Any)
}
```